# Spring Integration Async flow dsl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring integration in my code. Here I'm using scatter gather pattern and in the end I'm calling saveResponseAndGenerateApplicationResponse() flow. In the last flow I'm doing three operations - 1. saveResponse() 2. storeSomeData() 3.createApplicationResponse().

Below is my code for SpringIntegrationConfiguration -

```
 @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(saveRequestToDB())
                        .recipientFlow(getSomething()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.outputProcessor(aggregateResponse()))
            .to(saveResponseAndGenerateApplicationResponse());
  }

private IntegrationFlow saveResponseAndGenerateApplicationResponse() {
    return flow ->
        flow.enrichHeaders(h -> h.errorChannel("dbErrorChannel", true))
            .handle(someService, "saveResponse")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.errorChannel("ResponseErrorChannel", true))
            .handle(someService, "storeSomeData")
            .handle(someService, "createApplicationResponse")
            .logAndReply("response")
}
```

My requirement is to call storeSomeData() & createApplicationResponse() methods parallelly and not to wait for the storeSomeData() method's response instead we'll be returning createApplicationResponse() method's response as the response of the application. Is there any Async feature available out of the box in spring integration as java provides ControllableFuture.runAsync(), where I don't have to wait for one method's response and returning another methods response to the gateway ?

I'm doing something as below & it works fine but I want to do it using Spring integration -

```
.handle( (payload, headers) -> { CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> someService.storeSomeData( (ResponseModel) payload, headers.get("cusTx", String.class), headers.get("productType", String.class))); return someService.createApplicationResponse( (ResponseModel) payload, headers.get("httpStatusCode", Object.class)); })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in parallel, then you need to look into:

```
/**
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel} {@link #channel}
 * method specific implementation to allow the use of the 'subflow' subscriber capability.
 * Use the provided {@link Executor} for the target subscribers.
 * @param executor the {@link Executor} to use.
 * @param publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to specify
 * {@link PublishSubscribeSpec} options including 'subflow' definition.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public B publishSubscribeChannel(Executor executor,
        Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer) {
```

The provided `executor` would ensure that all of its subscribers are ran on threads from that executor.

To return only from the `createApplicationResponse` you need ensure that `storeSomeData` does not return anything. Otherwise there is no guarantee which answer is going to be pushed back to the requestor.

So, the solution for your current requirement might look like this:

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(executor(),
                        s -> s
                                .subscribe(f -> f.handle(someService, "storeSomeData"))
                                .subscribe(f -> f.handle(someService, "createApplicationResponse")))
```

Comment: Actually storeSomeData() method is going to return something but we are going to return createApplicationResponse() methods response because  storeSomeData() is going to take some time to finish but createApplicationResponse() is a quick one

Comment: So, you need to revise that API to be `void` or wrap such a `storeSomeData()` method call to something what would be `void` or return `null`. The returned value in Spring Integration is treated as a reply message payload. You also cannot use a `logAndReply()` after that `publishSubscribeChannel()` since this one becomes as a one more subscriber to this channel. You can move it inside a `subscribe()` sub-flow where you'd like to return a reply.